# Custom Controller and VF Pages for a Kanban

Tags: visualforce, custom-controller

Looking to get a little help with a custom controller and VF page for a Kanban we will use on our home screen. I have used the code from https://shrutisridharan.wordpress.com/2016/08/22/creating-a-kanban-view-for-leads/ and adjusted the code to display opportunities based on stages.

The error code i am getting is

*Map key Pre-Renewal to be Sent not found in map
Error is in expression '{!allOpps[stageName.value]}' in component  in page oppkanbanvfp*

which Line 79 of the VF page.

I have included the code below for the controller and VF page

**Controller**

```
public class OppKanbanCon {
    public static String OPP_MOVED = '{0} was moved successfully to {1}';

    public List<Schema.PicklistEntry> oppStageNames  { get; set; }
    public Map<String, List<Opportunity>> allOpps  { get; set; }

    public class UpdateStageName {
        public Boolean isSuccess;
        public String message;
    }

    public OppKanbanCon() {
        oppStageNames = Opportunity.StageName.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
        fetchOpps();
    }

    @RemoteAction
    public static UpdateStageName updateOppStagename( Id oppId, String newOppStageName ) {
        Opportunity oppDetails = [
            SELECT  Id
                    ,Name
            FROM    Opportunity
            WHERE   Id = :oppId
        ];

        oppDetails.StageName = newOppStageName;
        UPDATE oppDetails;

        UpdateStageName updatedOppDetails = new UpdateStageName();
        updatedOppDetails.isSuccess    = true;
        updatedOppDetails.message      = String.format( OPP_MOVED, new List<String>{ oppDetails.Name, newOppStageName } );

        return updatedOppDetails;
    }

    private void fetchOpps() {
        List<Opportunity> opportunities = [
            SELECT  Id
                    ,Name
                    ,CloseDate
                    ,StageName
                    ,Income__c
            FROM    Opportunity WHERE recordTypeId = '0120V000001lDYyQAM' AND (StageName != 'Closed Won' AND StageName != 'Closed Lost')
        ];

        allOpps = new Map<String, List<Opportunity>>();

        for( Opportunity opportunity : opportunities ) {
            if( !allOpps.containsKey( opportunity.StageName ) ) {
                allOpps.put( opportunity.StageName, new List<Opportunity>{ opportunity } );
            }
            else {
                allOpps.get( opportunity.StageName ).add( opportunity );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page controller="OppKanbanCon" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0" cache="false" expires="0">
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

            <title>Lead Kanban</title>

            <apex:slds />
            <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
            <link type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.3/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

            <style type="text/css">
                body {
                    padding: 1em;
                }
                .slds-item {
                    box-shadow: 0 0 10px gray;
                    border: none !important;
                    background-color: #fff;
                    border-radius: 0 !important;
                    border-left: 5px solid #56aadf !important;
                }
                .slds-title {
                    border-radius: 3px;
                    background-color: #e0e5ee;
                    border: 1px solid #d8dde6;
                    cursor: move;
                }
                .slds-col {
                    height: 520px;
                    overflow-y: auto;
                    border-left: 1px solid whitesmoke;
                }
                .slds-item-placeholder {
                    border: 2px dotted gray !important;
                    height: 5rem;
                }
                .moving-card {
                    opacity: 0.5;
                    transform: rotate( -5deg );
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="slds-scope">
                <!--Page Header-->
                <div class="slds-page-header slds-m-bottom--small" role="banner">
                    <div class="slds-media slds-media--center">
                        <div class="slds-media__body">
                            <p class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate slds-align-middle slds-text-heading--large">
                                <strong><i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Lead Kanban</strong>
                            </p>
                            <p class="slds-text-body--small page-header__info">Adjusting Lead Stages have never become so easy!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Kanban Column Headers-->
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <div class="slds-tabs--path" role="application">
                        <ul class="slds-tabs--path__nav" role="tablist">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!oppStageNames}" var="stageName">
                                <li class="slds-tabs--path__item slds-is-incomplete" role="presentation">
                                    <a class="slds-tabs--path__link" tabindex="-1" role="tab" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                        <span class="slds-tabs--path__title slds-text-heading--medium">{!stageName.label}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!--Kanban Columns-->
                <div class="slds-grid">
                    <apex:repeat value="{!oppStageNames}" var="stageName">
                        <div class="slds-col slds-size--3-of-12 slds-has-dividers--around-space slds-scrollable--y" name="{!stageName.value}">
                            <apex:repeat value="{!allOpps[stageName.value]}" var="Opp">
                                <div class="slds-item slds-m-around--small" id="{!Opp.Id}">
                                    <div class="slds-tile slds-tile--board">
                                        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider slds-m-bottom--small slds-title">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                                                <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{!Opp.Name}
                                            </a>
                                        </h3>

                                        <div class="slds-tile__detail slds-text-body--small">
                                            <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                <i class="fa fa-briefcase fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{!Opp.CloseDate}
                                            </p>

                                            <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                <i class="fa fa-building fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{!Opp.Income__c}
                                            </p>

                                            <p class="slds-truncate">
                                                <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;{!Opp.Email}
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </apex:repeat>
                        </div>
                    </apex:repeat>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/2.1.3/toastr.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $( ".slds-col" ).sortable(
                    {
                        connectWith: ".slds-col",
                        handle: ".slds-title",
                        placeholder: "slds-item slds-m-around--small slds-item-placeholder",
                        start: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( ui.item ).addClass( "moving-card" );
                        },
                        stop: function( event, ui ) {
                            $( ui.item ).removeClass( "moving-card" );

                            var oppId             = $( ui.item ).attr( "id" );
                            var newOppStageName   = $( ui.item ).parent().attr( "name" );

                            OppKanbanCon.oppStageNames(
                                oppId,
                                newOppStageName,
                                function( result, event ) {
                                    if( result.isSuccess ) {
                                        toastr.info( result.message );
                                    }
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    }
                );
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just don't have at least one Opportunity in each Stage, so some of the keys that you accumulate in `oppStageNames` don't exist in `allOpps`.

An easy fix would be to removethis code

```
        if( !allOpps.containsKey( opportunity.StageName ) ) {
            allOpps.put( opportunity.StageName, new List<Opportunity>{ opportunity } );
        }
```

where you lazy-add a child collection for each stage name found on an Opportunity, and instead iterate over  `oppStageNames` prior to the `Opportunity` loop, adding a child collection for each stage name.

Then, your Visualforce page can rely on having at minimum an empty list corresponding to each Opportunity stage.